# Storing a pointer within a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

```
int  var = 5;


int  *intptr = &var;

int *intptr1 = intptr;

std::cout << "adress of var   : " << intptr << std::endl;   //0x00EFFB05
std::cout << "adress of var   : " << &var << std::endl;     //0x00EFFB05
std::cout << "value of var    : " << var << std::endl;      // 5
std::cout << "value of var    : " << *intptr << std::endl;  // 5
std::cout << "adress of intptr: " << &intptr << std::endl;  //0x00EFFB44
std::cout << "adress of var   : " << intptr1 << std::endl;  //0x00EFFB05 /In my unterstanding, the adress of intptr should be here, instead we have the adress of var
```

In the line where i assign "var" to the "intptr" pointer, the adress of var becomes the value of the pointer.

In the line where i assign my pointer "intptr" to the pointer "intptr1", the adress of "intptr" doesnt become the value of "intptr1", but instead, the VALUE of "intptr" becomes the value of "intptr1", which is the adress of var.

1: Why this change of logic when assigning a pointer to a pointer?

2: And how do i store the address of "intptr" to "intptr1"?

Comment: Maybe seeing `int **intptr1 = &intptr` will give you an insight.

Comment: Assigning the *value* of a pointer to another pointer of the same type is no different than assigning the *value* of an `int` to another `int`.  You are making a *copy* of the *value*. Pointers are no different in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

There is no change of logic. If you want to assign an address, you need to use the address-of operator (&). You did this for `var` but not for `intptr`, so you get exactly what you asked for.

Try `int **intptr1 = &intptr;`. Note the difference in the type declaration. `intptr1` is not a pointer-to-int; it's a pointer-to-pointer-to-int.

Comment: Yes, but when doing: "int *intptr1 = &intptr" gave me an error message. So a double star ** fixes my issue. Thank you

Comment: A side note for @Moosey : Adding layers of indirection can solve thorny problems (many linked list implementations that show up around here would be helped greatly by taking advantage of pointers to pointers) but they can also be a sign that you haven't thought the problem through quite far enough and are headed for a conceptual disaster. Before you reach for that extra `*`, think hard on the downside of becoming what is derisively called a Three Star Programmer.